# Is the reaction between thiosulfate and hydronium an acid-base reaction?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism

Is the following reaction an acid-base reaction:

$$\ce{2 H3O+(aq) + S2O3^2-(aq) -> 3H2O(l) + SO2(g) + 1/8 S8(s)}$$

And if so, which is the acid and which is the base?

Comment: $\ce{H3O+}$ is the acid, $\ce{S2O3^2-}$ is the base, and they react to produce an unstable product that decomposes further, which is not an acid/base reaction.

Comment: could you write the reaction of decomposition

Comment: Why, it's $\ce{H2S2O3 -> H2O + SO2 + S}$

Comment: but the ph levels changes

Comment: Ivan,so you say the reaction is 2H3O+(aq)+S2O3-2(aq)=>3H2S2O3=>3H2O(l)+3SO2(g)+3/8S8(s)?

Comment: Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid%E2%80%93base_reaction) gives at least 7 different definitions of acid-base reactions, and they do not all require the formation of water + a salt.  A good example is in the OP; there is an acid and a base and they react.  Maybe you could call it a _neutralization_ reaction?  And presumably the counter ions not shown in the equation form ionic bonds with each other, as one is positively charged and the other negatively charged.  That still doesn't have to be a salt though.

Answer (score 3):

Two of the three acid-base theories (Brønsted and Lewis) also define an acid-base reaction while the third theory (Arrhenius) does not — it merely defines what acids and bases *are.*

In the Lewis theory, an acid-base reaction occurs when a lone pair donor interacts with a lone pair acceptor to form a new bond *without* a simultaneous redox reaction happening. The less complicated Brønsted-Lowry theory describes an acid-base reaction as a reaction in which a proton $\ce{H+}$ is transferred from an acid to a base, giving us a conjugate base and a conjugate acid, respectively.

As has been pointed out, your reaction is not a one-step reaction. Rather, we have to break it down into its constituent steps. The *first* step, a reaction of hydronium $\ce{H3O+}$ with thiosulfate $\ce{S2O3^2-}$ *has* to be an acid-base reaction because that is practically the only reaction hydronium undergoes.

$$\ce{2H3O+ + S2O3^2- -> H2S2O3 + 2 H2O}\tag{1}$$

The acid is the species that *donates* the transferred proton, the base is the species that *accepts* it. Therefore, we can assign the *acid* and *base* roles as shown in equation $(1')$.

$$\ce{2 \underset{acid}{H3O+} + \underset{base}{S2O3^2-} -> 2 \underset{conjugate base}{H2O} + \underset{conjugate acid}{H2S2O3}}\tag{$1'$}$$

The second reaction is a redox reaction. Thiosulfate (and therefore also its conjugate acid) has two sulfur atoms in the oxidation states of $\mathrm{+V}$ and $\mathrm{-I}$, respectively. These undergo a redox reaction leading to compounds of the oxidation state $\mathrm{+IV}$ (sulfurous acid $\ce{H2SO3}$) and $\pm0$ (elemental sulfur). We can use the full redox reaction determination algorithm, but I’m skipping that since it is a simple one-electron transfer.

$$\ce{H2S2O3 -> H2SO3 + 1/8 S8}\tag{2}$$

And finally, we have another decomposition namely that of sulfurous acid to sulfur dioxide $\ce{SO2}$ and water. This can be seen as the back-reaction of a Lewis acid-base reaction wherein water is the liberated Lewis base and sulfur dioxide the liberated Lewis acid. Indeed, the forward Lewis acid-base reaction (the reverse direction of this reaction) occurs, too. This reaction is in equilibrium, driven to the product side because of the volatility of $\ce{SO2}$.

$$\ce{H2SO3 (aq) <=>> H2O (l)  + SO2 (g) ^}\tag{3}$$

Therefore, the overall reaction is the sum of one Brønsted acid-base reaction, one redox reaction, and one Lewis acid-base reverse reaction.

$$\ce{2 H3O+ (aq) + S2O3^2- (aq) -> 3 H2O (l) + 1/8 S8 (s) + SO2 (g) ^}\tag{4}$$